# Building customized dashboard using amazon cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to create a customized dashboard to check user's properties that are stored in amazon cognito. Is it possible? if yes do let me know how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito doesn't target this use case in particular (bulk retrieval of user attributes). It exposes a ListUsers API but you would need to call getUserAttributes to retrieve each user's attributes.